# How to query a DynamoDB GSI with a RangeKey that uses a marshaller

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, nosql

I have a table, in that I have a secondary index. My secondary index uses DynamoDB marshalling.

How do I query the table on this GSI? The addRangeKeyCondition, supports only withS, and withN methods. How do I query it with my object? 
This is how I query it if the Range key is a string:

```
DynamoDBQueryExpression<RequestPerOfferItem> queryExpr = new DynamoDBQueryExpression<>();
queryExpr.withHashKeyValues(item).withRangeKeyCondition( "KeyName",
              new Condition().withAttributeValueList(new AttributeValue().withS(val)).withComparisonOperator(
                      ComparisonOperator.EQ));
```

But I cannot do this, as my range key uses a marshaller. How do I query my GSI using this range key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the marshaller yourself to get the String representation of the object:

```
public static class YourObjectMarshaller implements DynamoDBMarshaller<YourObject>
{
   public static final YourObjectMarshaller instance = new YourObjectMarshaller();
...
}
```

Then you can use it yourself as `YourObjectMarshaller.instance.marshall(obj)` and pass it as String withS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DynamoDBMapper, you can use the `@DynamoDBMarshalling` annotation and specify the `DynamoDBMarshaller` to use for your object.

```java
@DynamoDBMarshalling(YourObjectMarshaller.class)
public YourObject getYourObject() {
    ....
}
```